# Проблема с кодировкой

Tags: кодировка, html, bootstrap

Здравствуйте!
Учусь работать с bootstrap. Сделал простую страницу. Вместо русских букв отображаются знаки вопросов. В html файле добавил - `meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />`, на сервере, откуда запускается страничка, в файл `.htaccess` добавил `AddDefaultCharset UTF-8`. Не помогло. 
Скрин:
http://firepic.org/?v=2.2014-09-19_0u6j6mnuifdr.jpg

Comment: Покажите страницу.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В какой кодировке сохранен сам html файл?
Если работаешь через notepad++, то попробуй преобразовать весь файл в UTF-8 без БОМ или просто в UTF-8.

Comment: Это тоже пробовал. Тоже не помогло.

Comment: Т.е. тут это 100% проблема с кодировкой или, возможно, что-то другое?!

Comment: Похожая проблема была, но мне помогло выше написанное. Извини, но другого посоветовать не могу(

Comment: Помогла перекодировка, возможно, первый раз что-то не так сделал.

Answer (score 0):

Вот эту вот ересь:

```
< meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
```

как минимум следует заменить на кошерное

```
< meta charset="utf-8" />
```

Для информации: я зашел на ссылку выше со своего ноута с Linux Mint, где по умолчанию консоль utf-8, так у меня все украинские тексты отобразились корректно.

Comment: Да, спасибо, уже разобрался.
___

Всем спасибо за подсказки. Как тему закрыть?

Comment: @PavelNET, поставить галочку ниже правильного ответа *и нажать "закрыть" под самим вопросом, но галочка все-таки важнее*.